# Query Formula gives values that can't be summed using =sum()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

So I have two query formulas:

```
=iferror(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE('Index Sheet'!$C$2,"Table 1!A1:Z1000"),"Select sum(Col7) where Col1 = """&$A5&""" label sum(Col7)''",0))
```

and it repeats for every row with the A5 being dynamic reference.

I am also using the query select formula:

```
=iferror(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE('Index Sheet'!$C$3,"Table 1!A1:Z1000"),"Select Col7 where Col1 = """&$A5&""" label Col7''",0))
```

When I try to use the query sum formula it says `AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC` for most of the sheets I am referencing, so I'm forced to use the query select formula instead.

So long story short I am trying to sum certain certain parts of columns in this new sheet (eg. `H10:H15`), but the sums are not summing, they just return a "-". Please see my screenshots below:

Original Source (sheet the queries are referencing):
[image: Original Source]

New sheet query example:
[image]

New sheet I am trying to get the values over to (see sum function of D18):
[image: Sheet with Query formula]

The `=sum()` functions work when I use the query Sum to get the values, but for certain original sheets I can't use query sum because of `AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC` (some of the columns are merged etc.). So basically, forgive my poor explanation, how do I get to sum up these queried values if the query sum function can't put the values in the cells because of `AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC`, and the query select function are returning values that even though they appear like numbers can't be summed. I can't change the original sheets.

Comment: Can you link a sanitised copy of your sheet?

Comment: If this is due to mixed values in the queried columns, both text and numeric, or else just text, won't you need to somehow create a helper column where you first convert the text numbers to true numeric values, to allow the Query Sum to function?  Or possibly you could do this transform as part of the query formula.  Sharing a copy of your sheet(s) is necessary.